# How to use Fl_Tabs in pyFltk

Tags: python, fltk

I am trying to make a card game programs using Fl_Tabs or Fl_Wizard but can't find any instructions on how to do so in pyFltk. Is there an example or any documentation showing the basic code of creating the Fl_Tabs because I couldn't find *anything* on the Internet.

```
from fltk import *
x=Fl_Tabs(20,20,500,500)
x.show()
Fl.run()
```

When I run the above program that, nothing will show.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Example of how to use Fl_Tabs.  This is a python version of the one from Erco's cheat page

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# python version of http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk/#Fl_Tabs
#      _____  _____
#   __/ Aaa \/ Bbb \______________________
#  |    _______                           |
#  |   |_______|                          |
#  |    _______                           |
#  |   |_______|                          |
#  |    _______                           |
#  |   |_______|                          |
#  |______________________________________|
#
from fltk import *

def GroupAAA():
   aaa = Fl_Group(10,35,500-20,200-45,"Aaa")
   b1 = Fl_Button(50, 60,90,25,"Button A1"); b1.color(88+1)
   b2 = Fl_Button(50, 90,90,25,"Button A2"); b2.color(88+2)
   b3 = Fl_Button(50,120,90,25,"Button A3"); b3.color(88+3)
   aaa.end()

def GroupBBB():
   bbb = Fl_Group(10,35,500-10,200-35,"Bbb")
   b1 = Fl_Button( 50,60,90,25,"Button B1"); b1.color(88+1)
   b2 = Fl_Button(150,60,90,25,"Button B2"); b2.color(88+3)
   b3 = Fl_Button(250,60,90,25,"Button B3"); b3.color(88+5)
   b4 = Fl_Button( 50,90,90,25,"Button B4"); b4.color(88+2)
   b5 = Fl_Button(150,90,90,25,"Button B5"); b5.color(88+4)
   b6 = Fl_Button(250,90,90,25,"Button B6"); b6.color(88+6)
   bbb.end()

win = Fl_Window(500,200,"Tabs Example")
tabs = Fl_Tabs(10,10,500-20,200-20)
GroupAAA()
GroupBBB()
tabs.end()
win.end()
win.show()
Fl.run()
```